# Pausing game during call

Tags: sprite-kit, appdelegate

Where can I handle code for pausing game during incoming call. I know about

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

but during game, how can I call it (I can't call it from SKScene, nor from view controller - only from app delegate, but how can I from there run my piece of code belonging to view controller).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I figured it out, I used NSNotification, here is the line of code, put it inside view controller you want to handle it :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pauseGame) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
```